# Command prompt errorlevel issue after running sqlcmd

Tags: cmd, command-prompt, sqlcmd, errorlevel

My code is below:

```
CALL:ECHOCOLOR "Executing on server:[S059D526\TCH] db:CS filename:[9990294_UPDATE_Concessions.sql]." Cyan
SET CURRENT_SCRIPT="9990294_UPDATE_Concessions.sql"
if not exist "9990294_UPDATE_Concessions.sql" (
  CALL:ECHOCOLOR "skipping execution of file [9990294_UPDATE_Concessions.sql].  Possibly it was renamed because it has already ran" Yellow
)
if exist "9990294_UPDATE_Concessions.sql" (
  CALL:ECHOCOLOR "executing script [9990294_UPDATE_Concessions.sql]" Cyan
  sqlcmd -V 1 -r1 -E -S S059D526\TCH -d "CS" -i "9990294_UPDATE_Concessions.sql" -o "9990294_UPDATE_Concessions.sql.run_20120508_12_19_36.log"
)
CALL:ECHORESULT "result [OK=0,ERR=any other]: %errorlevel%" %errorlevel%
if NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO FINAL_ERROR
if exist "9990294_UPDATE_Concessions.sql" rename "9990294_UPDATE_Concessions.sql" "9990294_UPDATE_Concessions.sql.ok"
```

The problem that I face is with the `errorlevel`, because after I run the database script it always returns 0. This is because the instruction `CALL:ECHORESULT "result [OK=0,ERR=any other]: %errorlevel%" %errorlevel%`. If the script runs with error, it never goes to the `FINAL_ERROR`. I don't know how can I do the validation to stop the process when I have a script error.

Answer (score 1):

Your error checking logic is wrong.

`IF ERRORLEVEL N` is true if the errorlevel is >= N. So `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0` will never be true! (assuming errorlevels are not negative).

You want either

```
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto FINAL_ERROR
```

or

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto FINAL_ERROR
```

One other thing. You really should test the ERRORLEVEL immediately after the command that you are trying to test. I don't know how `:ECHORESULT` routine is coded, but it could potentially alter the current ERRORLEVEL value.